# CssResource defining only a Part of the Classes?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, clientbundle

I use GWT ClientBundle with CssResource.
I have a css file test.css with the following classes:

```
.c1 {
}

.c2 {
}
```

When I want to use classes from test.css I have to do the following in my application:

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {

    @Source({Css.DEFAULT_CSS })
    Css css();
}

public interface Css extends CssResource {

    String DEFAULT_CSS = "buddyis/mobile/client/views/ItemView.css";


    String c1();
    String c2();
}
```

The problem is that I have to define all the classes from test.css even if I don't use them. Is there a way that I have do define only the classes that I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the @NotStrict annotation to the CssResource.

This should solve your problem.